# List of Symbols in LaTeX

Tags: big-list

What are the list of symbols found in LaTeX for letters similar to these:

1. For Mobile Phone - `\mphone`
2. For Phone - `\phone`

What are the other symbols available like for email, home, etc..

Comment: Have a look at [“How to look up a symbol?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

Comment: Let me point that the `Comprehensive LaTeX symbols List` forgets the `fontawesome` package that give easy access to the fontawesome web fonts in LaTeX.

Comment: `texdoc fontawesome`, `texdoc marvosym`, `texdoc wasysym`, `texdoc dingbats` must be really useful.